# Regarding the Popup Window's UITextView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, popupwindow

I have `UIViewController Manager`

```
@interface Manager : UIViewController

@property   NSString *currentNameID;


@end

@interface Manager ()<UITextFieldDelegate>{
    sqlite3 *RECORDS;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    NSString *databasePath;
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;


}
```

In the Manager `UIViewController`, I'd like to create a Popup Window.
It is created as

```
-(void)createPopUpWindow
{
    //Component specs
    int gap = 20;//to update
    int bigButtonWidth = 70;//to update
    int componentverHeight = 40;//to update

    int numcomponentsvertically = 4;
    int numcomponentshorizontally = 3;
    int textViewW = bigButtonWidth*2;
    int smallButtonWidth = 20;
    int uiviewWidth = gap * 4 + bigButtonWidth * numcomponentshorizontally;
    int uiviewHeight = gap * 5 + componentverHeight * numcomponentsvertically;
    // create view popup
    int centerx = (int)(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2);
    int centery = (int)(self.view.bounds.size.height / 2);

    //Popup window
    int x = centerx - (int)(uiviewWidth/2);
    int y = centery - (int)(uiviewHeight/2);
    self.viewPopup = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, uiviewWidth, uiviewHeight)];
    self.viewPopup.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.viewPopup];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.viewPopup addGestureRecognizer:tap];



    self.idTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(gap, gap, textViewW, componentverHeight)];
    [self.idTextView setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
    self.idTextView.restorationIdentifier = @"idview";
    self.idTextView.delegate = self.viewPopup;
    [self.viewPopup addSubview: self.idTextView];

}

-(void)dismissKeyboard {
    if([self.currTextfield isEqualToString:@"idview"]){
        [self.idTextView resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Then I also need UITextView's callback function to get some information regarding the UITextView such as

```
    - (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing: (UITextField *) textField
    {
        textField.text = @"";
        self.currTextfield = textField.restorationIdentifier;
    }
```

Now the callback function is not working in the Popup Window.
I put `<UITextFieldDelegate>` at Manager as shown above. But it doesn't work.

How can I make it work so the UITextView's callback is called?
Then in this line, who should be assigned to delegate `self.idTextView.delegate = self.viewPopup;`
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes in your code:

1. You are using `UITextView` and you are setting protocol as `UITextFieldDelegate`. Either make `UITextViewDelegate` OR change `UITextField`.

If you are using `UITextViewDelegate`, you should use following delegate methods :

`- textViewShouldBeginEditing:
- textViewDidBeginEditing:
- textViewShouldEndEditing:
- textViewDidEndEditing:`

2. You are setting protocol to self class so need to change the line of code :
   `self.idTextView.delegate = self;`

Comment: Yeah careless. Thanks